# Extract URL from curled one-line text file using Batch

Tags: batch-file, curl, command-line

I'm new in batch files and I need help extracting an URL from a single-line txt-file using Batch.

This is the curl command:

```
curl -X "GET" %runone% -H "accept: application/json" -o runone.txt
```

The output stored in the file (runone.txt) is a single line like this:

```
{"meta":{"terms-and-conditions":{"href":"https://apps.censored.int/datasets/licences/general/"},"license":"CC-BY-4.0","copyright":"censored"},"data":{"link":{"href":"https://apps.censored.int/webapps/opencharts/content/20220620211737-879c62d3db4f29947daaf8140a3f9261a35e4c5b.png","type":"image/png"},"attributes":{"description":"","name":"opencharts","title":"Chart"},"type":"graphical_product"},"tracker":"tracker-dd80b7a5299e46ef8aa8de4041b12aeb","uid":""}
```

I only want to pick the **URL to the png-file** from the runone.txt (in this example: https://apps.censored.int/webapps/opencharts/content/20220620211737-879c62d3db4f29947daaf8140a3f9261a35e4c5b.png) and store it to a variable in batch.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you limited to plain shell? otherwise [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) might be useful to you.

Comment: jq could be an option too, but I have no knowledge with it. Especially how I use it extracting the URL described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q72693254.txt"

SET "pngurl="&FOR /f "usebackqtokens=11,*delims={:}" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO FOR %%e IN (%%c) DO IF NOT DEFINED pngurl SET "pngurl=%%~e"

ECHO pngurl=%pngurl%
GOTO :EOF
```

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then `%filename1%` does not need to be quoted, and then the `usebackq` can be  omitted.

Solution depends on the format of the output file being as described.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to parse the JSON File and exctract a link from it using Powershell and Batch like this code below :

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Parse JSON File And Exctract A Link From It Using Powershell And Batch
Set "JSON_File=%~dp0runone.txt"
set psCmd="&{(GC "%JSON_File%" | ConvertFrom-Json).data.link.href}"
Call :RunPS %psCmd% URL
Echo "%URL%"
pause & Exit
::-------------------------------------------------------------------
:RunPS <PassPSCMD> <RetValue>
@for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`Powershell %1`) do set "%2=%%i"
Goto:eof
:: End of :RunPS function
::-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the output is JSON, I'd suggest you have a look at the JSON-parser [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel). It'll save you a lot of trouble and headache, especially because of Batch its limitations.

```
xidel -s --method=GET -H "accept: application/json" "%runone%" -e "$json/data/link/href"
```

This opens the url and extracts the url to the png-file from the JSON. As `xidel` can open urls, there's no need for `curl`, or to save the JSON to a file.
"GET" is the default method, so you can probably do without `--method=GET`. Maybe the header isn't necessary either.

To assign the png-file-url to a variable:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('
  xidel -s --method=GET -H "accept: application/json" "%runone%" -e "$json/data/link/href"
') DO SET "pngurl=%A"
```

or alternatively:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('
  xidel -s --method=GET -H "accept: application/json" "%runone%" -e "pngurl:=$json/data/link/href" --output-format^=cmd
') DO %A
```

*(if you want use this command in a Batch-file, use `%%A` instead of `%A`)*